# Historical present(tenses usage accuracy)

Tags: tense, historical-present

- this is **historical present usage**
- Let's say you are a having a conversation with some random
  individual, your storytelling a **past event** during your **childhood** using **present tense** and you say:

> ''Dating back when I was a child, everytime we **go** to stores, I **tend** to look at gameboys **telling** to my dad, ''I **want** you to buy me that for my birthday''... and yadda yadda yadda...

Did I use the historical present correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps OP has misunderstood what [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) (also called dramatic present or narrative present) means. It actually refers to *using the present tense when narrating past events* - as, for example...

> *So I'm in the pub the other day, and this guy comes up to me and says [blah blah]...*

Note that (as in my example) this usage is *particularly* associated with casual / dialectal / non-standard speech, but can also occur in highly-polished literary contexts too (adding "immediacy").

The specific cited example is clumsily-constructed though. The initial adverbial element *dating back when* would be completely unacceptable to the vast majority of native speakers. It means *[ever] **since*** - which feasibly could be validly written as *dating back **to** when*, but personally I'd much prefer *back **from** when*).

There's also confusion regarding whether the word ***dating*** should be there at all. Whether or not it's present significantly affects the meaning (*with* = #1 below, *without* = #2). 
Discarding irrelevant details and simplifying things, the two most obvious possible meanings are...

> 1: ***Ever since*** I was a child I **have wanted** my Dad to buy me a Gameboy.
>    2: ***Back when*** I was a child I **wanted** my Dad to buy me a Gameboy.

(Note that in both cases, ***always*** could reasonably be included before ***wanted***.)

---

Turning to OP's specific adverbial clause *telling to my dad [what I told him],* this would more naturally be phrased as ***saying*** to my Dad. It could *feasibly* be added before the period in both my two shortened versions above. With #1, it specifies *what I have always done [and am still doing]*, whereas with #2 it's something I *did* (in the past, but not now).

I don't know which exact meaning (#1 / #2 above, or something completely different) OP intends, so it's not really worth me trying to rephrase it to a more "natural" form. But it doesn't have much to do with "historical present" as a grammatical concept. OP's cited example is just a *continuous* form *(**telling**)* in an optional adverbial clause. No different to, say,...

> *He **walked/walks/will walk** home, thinking deep thoughts*

...where obviously the "continuous" adverbial ***thinking*** clause applies to past, present, or future action.

Comment: Hello, I was so sick in the past 2 days that's why I can't make any reply even though I wanted to. What is OP by the way? That's all I wanted to ask and I undertand your #1 and #2 examples, which are the best thing to do to sound more natural and avoid awkwardness right.

Comment: It's not easy to explain exactly why, but I don't think *to **tend to** [do something]* is really suitable for your context. It means you *were inclined to,* but I'd have to say including it in something like *Back when I was a child I **tended to want** my Dad to buy me toys* sounds a bit "odd". A more natural / colloquial phrasing for that one would be *Back when I was a child I **used to want** my Dad to buy me toys* - where ***used to*** could imply repeated / habitual action (*frequently* asking for toys), as opposed to describing to a *continuous* state of desire with Simple Past.